# Is a locally compact Hausdorff quotient of a locally compact $\sigma$-compact first countable Hausdorff space always Frechet-Urysohn?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, first-countable

This question follows on from a previous one, which has been answered in the negative: [Is a locally compact Hausdorff quotient of a locally compact $\sigma$-compact first countable Hausdorff space always first countable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3776755/is-a-locally-compact-hausdorff-quotient-of-a-locally-compact-sigma-compact-fi)

Let $Y$ be a locally compact, $\sigma$-compact, first countable Hausdorff space and $q:Y\to X$ a quotient map with $X$ Hausdorff. Suppose that $X$ is locally compact. Is $X$ a Frechet-Urysohn space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\int}{\operatorname{int}}$
I realize this is a little old but since it hasn't been resolved, and I was thinking about [similar issues recently](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4844346/1210477):

Yes, $X$ must be Fréchet-Urysohn.

---

> **Lemma.** Under the given conditions, if $Y$ is exhaustible by compact sets $L_n\subseteq \int(L_{n+1})$, and $K\subseteq X$ is compact, then $K\subseteq q(\int(L_n))$ for some $n$.

**Proof.**  Suppose otherwise, and choose $x_n\in K\backslash q(\int(L_n))$ for each $n$.  Let $V_n=q^{-1}\left(X\backslash \bigcup_{k\geq n}\{x_k\}\right)$.  Note that for each $m$, only finitely many of the closed sets $q^{-1}(\{x_k\})$ intersect $\int(L_m)$, so $V_n\cap \int(L_m)$ is open.  Since this holds for all $m$ and $\{L_m\}$ is an exhaustion, $V_n$ is open.  But the sets $V_n$ are also saturated, so $\{q(V_n)\}$ is an open cover of $K$ with no finite subcover, contradicting compactness.

---

**Proof of main result.**

Suppose $x\in \overline{A}\subseteq X$.  Let $K\ni x$ be a compact neighborhood of $x$.  By the lemma, we have $K\subseteq q(\int(L_n))$ for some $n$.  We claim that for any open $V\supseteq q^{-1}(\{x\})$, there is some open set $U\ni x$ with $$q^{-1}(\overline{U})\cap L_n\subseteq V.\tag{*}$$

To see this, suppose otherwise, and consider the family of closed sets $\{q^{-1}(\overline{U})\cap L_n\backslash V\}$, where $U$ is neighborhood of $x$.  If these are nonempty, then they have the finite intersection property, hence by compactness of $L_n$, their intersection is non-empty.  But by the Hausdorff condition on $X$, the intersection of this family is empty, as we can always find neighborhood $U$ of $x$ with $x'\notin \overline{U}$, and then $q^{-1}(\{x'\})\cap q^{-1}(\overline{U})=\emptyset$, so the intersection can only contain points in $q^{-1}(\{x\})$, and these are also excluded as they lie in $V$.

Therefore, given any open $V$ as in the preceding paragraphs, there is such a $U$.  Since $x\in \overline{A}$ and $K\cap U$ is a neighborhood of $x$, $A\cap K\cap U\neq \emptyset$.  Because $$q(\int(L_n))\supseteq K\supseteq A\cap K\cap U\neq \emptyset,$$ there is some $$y\in q^{-1}(U)\cap \int(L_n)\cap q^{-1}(A)\subseteq V\cap q^{-1}(A),$$ with the inclusion following from (*). Thus every neighborhood $V$ of $q^{-1}(\{x\})$ intersects $q^{-1}(A)$, and so some $y\in q^{-1}(\{x\})$ lies in $\overline{q^{-1}(A)}$.  By the  Fréchet-Urysohn property of $Y$, we have a sequence $b_n\in q^{-1}(A)$ with $b_n\to y$, and therefore $q(b_n)\in A$ is a sequence with $q(b_n)\to q(y)=x$.

---

**Remarks.**

As can be seen from examining the proof, the lemma does not require any separation on $Y$, and only $T_1$ for the quotient $X$.  $Y$ need only be [exhaustible by compacts](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000025) (equivalently, $\sigma$-compact and weakly locally compact, so that every point has a compact neighborhood).

The proof of the main result itself does require $X$ to be locally compact Hausdorff, though $Y$ need only be exhaustible by compacts and Frechet-Urysohn.

Answer (score 1):

I describe an example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2603289/4280) including the argument why the quotient space (there called $Y$ is not Fréchet-Urysohn (namely the map $q$ is not hereditarily quotient). The space we take a quotient of is a $\sigma$-compact and locally compact subspace of $\Bbb R$, so fits the bill.

The Arens space $S_2$ (which is Hausdorff), described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3775107/4280) as a quotient of a countable disjoint sum of convergent sequences (clearly a $\sigma$-compact locally compact first countable Hausdorff space), and is a classic example of a sequential but not Fréchet-Urysohn space.

Comment: The question requires the quotient to be locally compact, which neither of your examples are.

Comment: @EricWofsey Oops, I read only the first sentence...

Comment: I'll leave the examples as bonus ones for the first question. They don't work as yet for the second...